# User.ReadWite.All & b2c ownership/security

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We have a few B2C tenants and at a pretty high level I am being asked to provide users with User.ReadWite.All permissions. While I'm ok giving this to an application that has its code reviewed by an administrator, I'm not real keen on letting non-administrator type individuals have this right, though maybe I am not understanding b2c or that graph access over accounts.

Its my impression that having that permission would allow those users to do things like delete owners of the subscription, if not thousands of b2c users. While I can accept if the developers screwed up and it deleted all the users of their application, I can't accept that the b2c can't be used anymore because owners have been deleted or had their passwords reset or something.

I couldn't find anything about this, but I'm *hoping* that owners of the b2c would be immune from that permission, so if I gave it, I wouldn't have to worry about losing control over it.

The developers (MS consultants) are requesting this access to change a custom extension attribute on b2c users.

Thanks for any insight, just trying to do the right thing from a security and process perspective.

Comment: Kudos for checking. Often security is left behind.

Answer (score 0):

User Read Write All permissions will give the user ability to delete all users from B2C except themselves - that includes owners of the subscription and global administrators.

There are two types of user in the B2C directory, portal users and customers.

Customers can't sign-in to the azure portal, and directory users can't sign-in on your user flows - but each can exist as both personas.

You would *never* give customers delegated read write permissions in your directory for the reasons you mentioned.

Portal users can be assigned Azure Roles. In your case, it sounds like the developer needs to be invited to the Azure Portal for management of B2C and assigned the [External ID User Flow Attribute Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/permissions-reference#external-id-user-flow-attribute-administrator) role. The developer can then use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://aka.ms/ge)* to update the user attributes.

You can learn more about B2C specific [roles and resource access controls here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/roles-resource-access-control).

*to access a specific directory when using Microsoft Graph API you need to specify the tenant in the URL, I.E., [https://aka.ms/ge?tenant={yourtenant}.onmicrosoft.com](https://aka.ms/ge?tenant=%7Byourtenant%7D.onmicrosoft.com)

Comment: Thanks.  I gave the developers that right.  Hopefully it lets them just modify the custom attributes of customers and not any of the users, that would be great.  Really wish b2c had a role for 'customer administrator' instead of just 'user administrator'.